# PL/SQL Trigger in Oracle errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

i don't know how to start !!
i have a work in oracle database,and it is all about triggers and constraints ...
the work is to create triggers and constraints on some tables of database of league of hokey ...
and since i'm new , and not familiar with triggers i have a lot of errs!!!

let's take these two tables as exemple :

1/ "equipe" (means team) table :

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID_EQ                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
NOM                                                VARCHAR2(50)
ENREGISTRMENT                                      VARCHAR2(50)
ID_LIG                                             NUMBER(6)
ID_CAPITAINE                                       NUMBER(6)
ID_ENT                                             NUMBER(6)
```

2/ "joueur" (means player) :

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID_JOU                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
NUMERO                                             NUMBER(4)
POSITION                                           VARCHAR2(50)
ID_EQ                                              NUMBER(6)
```

where :

"id_eq" and "id_jou" are primary keys.

"joueur.id_eq" is referenced to "equipe.id_eq".

"equipe.id_capitaine" is referenced to "joueur.id_jou".

i want to create a trigger that write a msg of err if the user insert in or update the table "equipe" where the "capitaine"  is not a player in the team ("equipe") , i try a lot , buttt ... always the msg:

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

This is one of the triggers , if someone can find the err and fix it , or suggest a better one :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER capitaine_in_equipe
before UPDATE OR INSERT ON equipe
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  id_p joueur.id_eq%TYPE;
BEGIN
if (:new.iq_capitaine is not null ) then
   SELECT id_eq INTO id_p 
   FROM joueur
   WHERE id_jou = :new.iq_capitaine;
   IF ( id_p != :new.id_eq ) THEN
      raise_application_error(-20100,' the captain is not a player of the team');
   END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

and if you know some good references of triggers, pl/sql Oracle for biggeners put it, please!

thank you ;)

Comment: `show errors` will list all errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, there are other way to implement your logic, but if you want to use your trigger, the following works for me

Create equipe:

```
CREATE TABLE equipe
( ID_EQ number(6) not null,
NOM varchar2(50),
ENREGIS number(6),
ID_CAPITAINE number(6),
ID_ENT number(6),
CONSTRAINT equipe_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_EQ)
);
```

Create joueur:

```
create table joueur
(ID_JOU number(6) not null,
NUMERO number(4),
POSITION varchar2(50),
ID_EQ number(6),
CONSTRAINT joueur_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_jou)
);
```

Alter both with the foreign key:

```
alter table equipe add(CONSTRAINT fk_equipe
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CAPITAINE)
REFERENCES joueur(ID_JOU));


alter table joueur add(CONSTRAINT fk_joueur
FOREIGN KEY (id_eq)
REFERENCES equipe(ID_EQ));
```

Create your trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER capitaine_in_equipe
before UPDATE OR INSERT ON equipe
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  id_p joueur.id_eq%TYPE;
BEGIN
if (:new.id_capitaine is not null ) then
   SELECT id_eq INTO id_p 
   FROM joueur
   WHERE id_jou = :new.id_capitaine;
   IF ( id_p != :new.id_eq ) THEN
      raise_application_error(-20100,' the captain is not a player of the team');
   END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Notice in your tables definition, you mentioned a column `id_capitaine`. In your trigger you used the name `iq_capitaine`. I'm not sure if that reflects your real code or just a typo here.

Comment: Thank you Hawk, it works after correcting the mistake !

Comment: @M.os.i Glad it helped. You can upvote and choose the answer as a correct one if it is. :)